# Dynamically create select options using material UI create

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]I'm very new to material ui react . I tried creating select options dynamically but couldn't succeed , is there any way different method to create select options dynamically. I tried to create codesandbox but couldn't due to some error.Below is my code. Please help.

```
import React from "react";
import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

const age = ["Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"];
export const SelectBa = ({}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }} size={size}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
        >
          {age.map((age) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={age}
              value={age}
              style={getStyles(age, personName, theme)}
            >
              {age}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SelectBa />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Comment: I realize that you are using the same name to render the list. Replace the list name age with ages.
const ages = ["Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"];
Also, include the error console message in the description

Comment: The above code is working fine ,my mistake I added age twice, but i would like to know is there any other way to achieve this dynamic select options. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @FábioRibeirodeCarvalho without defining const age [ten, twent] , is it possible to achieve. Because different user may different data, it should be dynamic generated not hard-coded. Thanks

Comment: Exactly what do You mean by "create select options dynamically"?

Comment: @HamedSiaban without hard coding the options ,can I do it dynamically?

Comment: You mean You want user to add options?

Comment: Yes.. because every user has there own date. Let them add their own options. I want it to be reusable select component. If i add my own select options , it won't be reusable. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have Your options in a state and then update it with user inputs.

```
import React from "react";
import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import { Button, OutlinedInput, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const SelectBa = ({}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
  const [ageList, setAgeList] = React.useState(["Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"]);
  const [newAge, setNewAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Name"
        value={newAge}
        onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
          setNewAge(event.target.value)
        }
      />
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          newAge && setAgeList([...ageList, newAge]);
          setNewAge("");
        }}
      >
        Add option
      </Button>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }} size="medium">
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
        >
          {ageList.map((age) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={age}
              value={age}
              // style={getStyles(age, personName, theme)}
            >
              {age}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SelectBa;
```

User will type the new option in the first TextField and by pressing the Button, the value will add to the options list.

Comment: But this will be autocomplete component, I'm building select component which can be reusable. Is it possible to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand what You want exactly. Can You express it with some images?

Comment: Added image above, my requirement is i have added values 
const age = ["Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty"];   which is hardcoded, I want user to add it according to their requirement. which means these values should be generated dynamically using material ui.

Comment: I think the updated answer will solve Your problem.

Comment: @ I'm really Thankful for your reply. But i want only the select component without any button added to it. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. select component does not have the ability to add options by itself. if you saw a sample in a site that can do that I would be happy to see that.

Comment: I'm new to this react. what was the requirement is i should not create hardcoded values for options, may be with the help of props we can add options & pass the same to select. I'm not sure, is it possible to achieve in this way ? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248517/discussion-between-hamed-siaban-and-advi).